# Solving the equation $\nabla u=f$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a open set, $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)=C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ and $D'(\Omega)$ the set of distributions. Suppose that $f_i\in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$. Define $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_N)$ and $$S=\{v\in (C_0^\infty(\Omega))^N:\ \operatorname{div}v=0\}$$

Assume that $\langle f,v\rangle=0$ for any $v\in S$, where $\langle f,v\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^N\langle f_i,v_i\rangle$. How can one prove that there exist $u\in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ such that $\nabla u=f$?

Thank you.

Comment: The usual way, I assume. You define $u(0) = 0$, and $u(x) = \int_\gamma f(y) \cdot ds(y)$ along any contour joining $x$ with 0. To show that this definition uniquely defines your function $u$, you need to show that along any closed loop $C$,  $\int_C f(y) ds(y) = 0.$ That's where your condition comes in.

Comment: Sorry about the question @RayYang, but how do you define $f(y)$? I'm asking, because for instance, $f$ is only a distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version of de Rham's result in his book *Differentiable Manifolds* ($\S 20$ to $\S 22$).

Luc Tartar has a presentation of a similar version of your result [here](http://portail.mathdoc.fr/PMO/PDF/T_TARTAR-150.pdf), please see page 30 bottom, where $f\in \big(H^1_0(\Omega)\big)'\subset \mathcal{D}'$.

Amrouche and Girault extended the result to $f\in \big(W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)\big)'$ (Theorem 2.8 [here](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128452/CzechMathJ_44-1994-1_10.pdf)) for Lipschitz $\Omega$, they said de Rham's theorem took too long to establish.

Both above literatures exploit close range theorem to prove, i.e., $\mathrm{Im}(\nabla) = \mathrm{ker}(\nabla\cdot)^{\perp}$.

[This paper](http://www.csm.ro/reviste/Revue_Mathematique/pdfs/2008/5-6/mardare_sorin.pdf) presented a special case of de Rham's theorem (please see Theorem 2.1 and 4.1), which is exactly your question.

I don't know if there is any proof based solely on functional analysis.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to add two sources that I have just found: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.unice.fr%2F~jsimon%2Fpubs%2FSimon-E7.pdf&ei=80m2UZneHKO-0gG68IGoDw&usg=AFQjCNFQp8u79ZWl_xNNn2A35hajp5jgjw&sig2=XraVh5wrODONk9Ev66RO4w and http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Incompressible-Navier-Stokes-Equations-Sciences/dp/1461459745/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1370900917&sr=8-1&keywords=mathematical+tools+navier#reader_1461459745 chpater 4

Comment: @Tomás Thanks, Amrouche and Girault said de Rham's theorem is way too powerful and we only need a result similar in Sobolev spaces. Also the de Rham's Theorem 17' (and 17) in the first paper you mentioned, is the last part of $\S 22$ in the *Differentiable Manifolds* book, but you have to read through $\S 20$ to get all those settings... :)

Comment: You are right. At least for me, the more analytical proof presented in those papers is more suitable. The topological setting is (at least for me) unnecessary, nonetheless, its is a beautiful theory.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Are you familiar with the application of this result in the context of Navier-Stokes equations, to "recover" the pressure?

Comment: @Pedro You mean get a post-processed pressure based on the velocity? It depends on which formulation you used though. If you use velocity-(pseudo)stress formulation, pressure is obtained by an explicit formula. If you use tradition formulation, you still have to use Lagrange multiplier to get pressure.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I suspect my question is very basic and is related only to understanding of the concept of distribution, but I'm not sure. I've posted it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017394/is-a-function-with-values-in-mathcald-omega-an-element-of-mathcald).