# Is a function with values in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ an element of $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega\times(0,T))$?.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

*The question is in the end of the post. First, I need some preliminary considerations.*

In the [Temam's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22This+enables+us+to+differentiate+%22+temam&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvnrPBga7QAhXBE5AKHaFyCgEQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22This%20enables%20us%20to%20differentiate%20%22%20temam&f=false) (as well as in the [Dautray's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=D6RrNWdUZx4C&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=%22It++is++thus+legitimate+to+differentiate%22&source=bl&ots=ay9M6jDVn2&sig=AtDHuaHRjbJKztKtuf-y3DnxolY&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCnvTVga7QAhUCD5AKHQXUBA0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22It%20%20is%20%20thus%20legitimate%20to%20differentiate%22&f=false)), the author proves that there exists $u\in C([0,T];H)\cap L^2(0,T;V)$ with $u'\in L^2(0,T;V')$ such that
$$u_t(t)-Au(t)=f(t)\quad\text{in}\quad V',\qquad\forall\ t\in(0,T),\tag{1}$$
where $f\in L^2(0,T;V')$ is given and $A:V\to V'$ is the operator defined by $$\langle Av,w\rangle_{V',V}=(v,w)_{H_0^1(\Omega)},\quad\forall \ v,w\in V.$$
The spaces are defined by $V={\overline{\mathcal{V}}}^{H^1(\Omega)\times H^1(\Omega)}$ and $H={\overline{\mathcal{V}}}^{L^2(\Omega)\times L^2(\Omega)}$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary and
$$\mathcal{V}=\{v\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)\times\mathcal{D}(\Omega)\mid\operatorname{div} v=0\}.$$

After proving existence the author considers the functions
$$U(t)=\int_0^tu(s)\;ds,\qquad F(t)=\int_0^Tf(s)\;ds.$$
From the regularity of $u$ and $f$ we have $U\in C([0,T];V)$ and $F\in C([0,T];V')$. And integrating $(1)$ we get
$$u(t)-u(0)-AU(t)=F(t)\quad\text{in}\quad V',\qquad\forall \ t\in(0,T).$$
This implies
$$\langle u(t)-u(0)-\Delta U(t)-F(t),v\rangle_{V',V}=0,\quad\forall\ v\in V,\;t\in(0,T).$$
Identifynig (by extension) $S(t):=u(t)-u(0)-\Delta U(t)-F(t)$ with a element of $H^{-1}(\Omega)$, it follows [as consequence](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22This+enables+us+to+differentiate+%22+temam&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvnrPBga7QAhXBE5AKHaFyCgEQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Combining%20the%20results%20of%20Propositions%22&f=false) of the "[Rham's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416677/solving-the-equation-nabla-u-f/416851?noredirect=1#comment4140066_416851)" that, for each $t\in (0,T)$, there exists $P(t)\in\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ such that
$$u(t)-u(0)-\Delta U(t)-F(t)=\nabla P(t)\quad\text{in}\quad\mathcal{D}'(\Omega).\tag{2}$$

After justifying that $\nabla P\in C([0,T]; [H^{-1}(\Omega)]^2)$ and $P\in C([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$, the author says that we can "differentiate $(2)$ in the $t$ variable, in the distribution sense in $Q:=\Omega\times (0,T)$", which yields
$$u_t-\Delta u-f=\nabla p\quad\text{in}\quad\mathcal{D}'(Q),\tag{3}$$
where $p=\partial_t P$.

> **Question:** It is not clear for me how to get $(3)$ from $(2)$. To differenciate $(2)$ with respect to $t$ in the sense of $\mathcal{D}'(Q)$ we need to indentify the terms of $(2)$ with elements of $\mathcal{D}'(Q)$ , right? How is this identification made?
>
> To prove $(3)$ we have to show that, for each $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}(Q)$, 
>   $$\langle u_t-\Delta u-f,\varphi\rangle=\langle \nabla (\partial_t P),\varphi\rangle.$$
>   Assuming that $P\in \mathcal{D}'(Q)$, we have
>   $$\langle \nabla (\partial_t P),\varphi\rangle
> =\langle \partial_t (\nabla P), \varphi\rangle
> \overset{(2)}{=}\langle \partial_t (u(t)-u(0)-\Delta U(t)-F(t)), \varphi\rangle,$$
>   but why is $P$ in $\mathcal{D}'(Q)$ and why
>   $$\langle \partial_t (u(t)-u(0)-\Delta U(t)-F(t)), \varphi\rangle=\langle u_t(t)-\Delta u(t)-f(t), \varphi\rangle?$$

Comment: I don't want to wade through all the spaces in the question, but the answer to the question in the title is "if it's regular enough, then yes". Let $g \colon (0,T) \to \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ and $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega \times (0,T))$. Then we can write $\varphi_t \colon x \mapsto \varphi(x,t)$, and look at the function $t \mapsto g(t)[\varphi_t]$. If $g$ is nice enough, that function is integrable on $(0,T)$, and we have a $G \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega\times(0,T))$ per $$G[\varphi] = \int_0^T g(t)[\varphi_t]\,dt.$$

Comment: I think what you need here is some version of L. Schwartz' kernel theorem, which states that $\mathcal{D}'((0,T),\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)) = \mathcal{D}'((0,1)\times \Omega)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Consider the map $T:L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))\ni g\mapsto T(g):=G\in\mathcal{D}'(\Omega\times (0,T))$, where $G$ is the distribution that you have defined.
Let $\partial_t T(g)$ be the (scalar) distributional derivative (w.r.t. $t$) of $T(g)$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega\times (0,T))$.
Let $u'$ be the (vector) distributional derivative of $g$ in $\mathcal{D}'(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.
If $u'$ is regular enough, $T(u')$ is well- defined. Do you know if the equality $\partial_t T(g)=T(u')$ holds?

Comment: I don't _know_ it, but I can't imagine what pathologies would cause it to not hold, despite both sides being well-defined. I'm rather convinced it does hold whenever both sides make sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there any reference for your first comment, a book which contains that definition of $G$?

Comment: I don't know. Probably. It's the natural thing if you consider the case where $g$ is a continuous function $(0,T) \to C(\Omega)$ [which can naturally be identified with a function $\tilde{g} \in C(\Omega\times (0,T))$] and generalise.

Comment: Some remark: Actually Temam is wrong here, one can't apply deRham's theorem in this case as $F \in L^2(0,T;V')$ and $V'$ is no distribution space. Even an extension  wouldn't do the trick as the pressure would be 'almost' arbitrary. One has to assume $f \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ for example. If you are interested, look at the paper 'On the identification $H=H'$ in the Lions theorem and a related error' by J. Simon on page 7 where he cites this passage of Temam's book.

Comment: @MarvinF I really appreciate your comment. After extending from $V'$ to $H^{-1}$ the argument works, right? But the result is not good because there are a lot of possilble extensions and thus there are a lot of possible pressures (because the pressure depends on the extension), right? Am I right? Is this the main point?

Comment: @Pedro Yes, you are absolutely right, that is the main point. Let's say $f \in L^2(0,T;V')$ then we have shown that there is pair $(u,p)$ that solves $\partial_t u - \Delta u + \nabla p = \overline{f}$, where $\overline{f}$ is the extension of $f$ such that $<\overline{f},v>_{H^{-1},H_0^1}=<f,v>_{V',V}$ for all $v \in V$. Further let $\pi \in L^2(0,T;L^2(Ω)$ be arbitrary. Then $(u,p+\pi)$ is a solution for the extension $\overline{f}+\nabla \pi$. Indeed, $<\nabla \pi,v>_{H^{-1},H_0^1}=-(\pi,\text{div} v)_{L^2(Ω)}=0$ vanishes for all $v \in V$. Thus the NS eq provide no info on the pressure.

Answer (score 2):

I will focus on the main question of whether a continuous mapping from $(0,T)$ to $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ is a distribution in $\mathcal{D}'((0,T)\times\Omega)$.

In analogy to the definition
$$
\mathcal(D)'(\Omega) = \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{D}(\Omega), \mathbb{C})
$$
is is possible to define vector-valued distributions, i.e., distributions with values in a locally convex space $E$ by
$$
\mathcal{D}'(\Omega, E) = \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{D}(\Omega), E).
$$
Then is possible to show that the space $\mathcal{C}(\Omega; E)$ of $E$-valued continuous functions can be embedded into $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega,E)$. I think what you need here is this for the case $E=\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ then you get in particular that
$$
\mathcal{C}((0,T),\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}'((0,T),\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)).
$$
The other ingredient you need is L. Schwartz kernel theorem, which states that
$$
\mathcal{D}'(\Omega_1,\mathcal{D}'(\Omega_2))= \mathcal{D}'(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2).
$$
Combining these results yields
$$
\mathcal{C}((0,T),\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}'((0,T),\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)) = \mathcal{D}'((0,t)\times \Omega)
$$
as you need. Providing all the details for the above arguments would need more space than an answer here allows, but you can find them for example in the book "Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels" by F. Trèves or in the book "Lectures on Mixed Problems in Partial Differential Equations and Representations of Semi-groups" by L. Schwartz.

Answer (score 0):

$P$ belongs to $\mathcal{D}'(Q)$ because $C([0,T]; L^2(\Omega))\subset L^2(0,T; L^2(\Omega))\cong L^2(\Omega\times (0,T))\subset\mathcal{D}'(Q)$ and $\langle \partial_t (u(t)-u(0)-\Delta U(t)-F(t)), \varphi\rangle=\langle u_t(t)-\Delta u(t)-f(t), \varphi\rangle$ by the explanation in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2027049/70305) post.